# Unable to import HttpModule in nest.js

Tags: nestjs

I am trying to import the HttpModule module in nest.js, but I am unable to. I get the following error

```
src/app.module.ts:1:18 - error TS2724: '"@nestjs/common"' has no exported member named 'HttpModule'. Did you mean 'HttpCode'?
```

This is my module.ts code

```
import { Module, HttpModule } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Module({
  imports: [HttpModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I also installed the module using

```
npm i --save @nestjs/axios
```

Comment: Change your import to `import { HttpModule } from '@nestjs/axios'` https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/9385#issuecomment-1079452560

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change your import to `import { HttpModule } from '@nestjs/axios'`

[nestjs/axios](https://github.com/nestjs/axios/blob/master/lib/http.module.ts)

[The HttpModule exported from the @nestjs/common package has been deprecated and will be removed in the next major release. Instead, please use the @nestjs/axios package (otherwise, there are no API differences).](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/9385#issuecomment-1079452560)